# npm package error - Cannot find module 'users-node'

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, user-management

I installed the users-node package on my Windows7 machine using `npm install users-node` - great success!

Code:

```
...    
var usermgr = require('users-node')(options, app);
...
```

But when I run my node server I get:

```
Error: Cannot find moduel 'users-node'
```

I implemented the code suggested on this page: https://npmjs.org/package/users-node but I could not download the repository from GitHub - link is broken: https://github.com/dpweb/users-node.

What do I need to do to implement users-node? I need to do users management, so do simple user login on a chat app using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/), [Socket.io](http://socket.io/) and [express](http://expressjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you didn't install it with **-g** option?

If so you need to set `NODE_PATH` [environment variable](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

The default path for **Windows** is:

> %AppData%\Roaming\npm\node_modules

In case you didn't install it globally, you must place your **app.js** file beside the **node_modules** directory which is created after you run `npm install users-node`

Comment: I've got ".....;C:\Node" in my 'PATH' system variable. Are you saying that I should create a new system variable i.e. NODE_PATH and add %AppData%\Roaming\npm\node_modules to that?

Comment: No I definitely did not install it globally using -g.

Comment: Try this: Open **Command Prompt**, create a new directory, go to that directory, run `npm install users-node`, open **node** interactive shell (ie. type `node`), and then type `require('users-node');`. It shouldn't throw any exceptions if you installed the module correctly.

Comment: my app.js file IS beside the node_modules directory.

Comment: thanks I'll try that "fresh install" approach quick. If it works I've obviously got an issue somewhere else. Perhaps the order in which I require things caused this?

Comment: require('users-node'); threw an error :( Cannot find module 'users-node'

Comment: Does the `node_modules` directory contain `users-node` module?

Comment: Looks like `users-node` module is broken. `npm install users-node` fails on my ubuntu. For user management/authentication stuff you can try `passport` module.